# Change cell value in a row based on others

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following table with two columns and two inputs each:

```
<table id="ASD" style="border:1px black solid">
<thead>
<th>Columna 1</th>
<th>Columna 2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr name="1" style="border:1px black solid">
    <td  style="border:1px black solid" ><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="1_1">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="1_1"></td>
    <td  style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="1_1">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="1_1_2"></td>
  </tr>

    <tr name="2" style="border:1px black solid">
    <td style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="2_1">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="2_1"></td>
    <td style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="2_2">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="2_2"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr name="3">
    <td style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="3_1"><label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="3_1"></td>
        <td  style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="3_2"><label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="3_2"></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I would ike that if, I click 'Si' on the first cell, the second one becomses automatically marked.

This is my JS so far, I am trying to do the following: When 'Si' is clicked in a row, find the closest TR and get the attribute name.
Once I have the attr name, **as its unique per row**, I can simply locate the tr and go to the second cell, find the input of the class 'c1s' and set it to checked.

The last part is the one I'm missing as I can't seem to retrieve the attr name from `<tr>`.

```
$(".c1s").click(function(){
alert("Click Si");
var id_col = $('#ASD').closest('tr').attr("name");
console.log(id_col);
alert(id_col)
})
```

**FIDDLE**:

https://jsfiddle.net/f7cqxyLy/1/

Can anyone help out?

Comment: This should fix a bit of your problem, https://jsfiddle.net/f7cqxyLy/2/. but its hard to know what you mean by second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just locate the indexes of your clicked cell and modify them to move to the other column.

```
window.onload = function () {
                    $(".c1s").click(function () {
                        var colIndex = $(this).parent().index()
                        var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index()

                        var table = document.getElementById("ASD")
                        var cell= table.rows[rowIndex+1].cells[colIndex+1]
                        cell.children[1].checked=true
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Worked as expected! Muchas gracias Oscar ;)!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the closest tr's attributes with this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().attr('name')
```

You can not use specific id's for the selector. You must use 'this' for the call to be relative. then get the next sibling with the next() call. better do a null-check before using it though.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<table id="ASD" style="border:1px black solid">
<thead>
<th>Columna 1</th>
<th>Columna 2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr name="1" style="border:1px black solid">
    <td  style="border:1px black solid" ><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="1_1">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="1_1"></td>
    <td  style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="1_2">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="1_2"></td>
  </tr>

    <tr name="2" style="border:1px black solid">
    <td style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="2_1">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="2_1"></td>
    <td style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="2_2">
    <label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="2_2"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr name="3">
    <td style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="3_1"><label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="3_1"></td>
        <td  style="border:1px black solid"><label>Sí</label><input type="radio" class="c1s" name="3_2"><label>No</label> <input type="radio" class="c1n" name="3_2"></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
$(".c1s").click(function(){
     var row = $(this).closest('tr');
     $(row).find('.c1s').each(function(){
         $(this).prop('checked',true);
     });
});

$(".c1n").click(function(){
     var row = $(this).closest('tr');
     $(row).find('.c1n').each(function(){
         $(this).prop('checked',true);
     });
});
```

JSFiddle Link for same

https://jsfiddle.net/f7cqxyLy/4/

Answer (score 0):

check out this fiddle and play with this line `$(this).closest("td").find(".c1n").attr('checked',true);` 
if you have some more query

https://jsfiddle.net/f7cqxyLy/5/

Comment: Hello, this will do it for all the row, but what if I had some columns in the same row I dont want it to change?